# Remover o style adicionado com .css() function com jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Estou mudando CSS com jQuery e preciso remover o style que adicionei:

```
if(cor != 'ffffff') $("body").css("background-color", cor); else // remover style ?
```

A linha acima é executada sempre que uma cor é selecionada usando um seletor de cores, quando o mouse se move sobre uma roda de cores.

Não consigo fazer isso com css, com "background-color", "none" porque ele removerá o estilo padrão dos arquivos css. Eu só quero remover o estilo inline de cor de fundo adicionado pelo jQuery.

Comment: [jQuery removeAttr() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_removeattr)

Answer (score 1):

Deixar `transparent` pode resolver o problema.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul > li').on('click', function(){
      var cor   = $(this).data('cor');
      var body  = $('body');
      
      body.css('background-color', cor);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body></body>

<ul>
<li data-cor="#FF0000">Cor 1</li>
<li data-cor="#FFFF00">Cor 2</li>
<li data-cor="#0000FF">Cor 3</li>
<li data-cor="#00FF00">Cor 4</li>
<li data-cor="transparent">Nenhuma</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar a propriedade para uma cadeia vazia, para fazer isso:

```
$("body").css("background-color", "");
```

Ou remover o atributo completo, o problema seria que todos estilos inline do elemento seriam removidos:

```
 $("body").removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

Há várias maneiras de remover uma propriedade CSS usando jQuery:

**1. Configurando a propriedade CSS como seu valor padrão (inicial)**

```
.css("background-color", "transparent")
```

> Veja o [valor inicial para a propriedade CSS no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-color). Aqui, o valor
>   padrão é transparente. Você também pode usar `inherit` para várias
>   propriedades CSS para herdar o atributo de seu pai. Em CSS3 / CSS4,
>   você também pode usar `initial`, `revert` ou `unset`, mas essas
>   palavras-chave podem ter suporte limitado ao navegador.

**2. Removendo a propriedade CSS**

Uma sequência vazia remove a propriedade CSS:

```
.css("background-color","")
```

**3. Removendo todo o style do elemento**

```
.removeAttr("style")
```